# Very difficult recursive regexp in PHP

Tags: php, regex, recursion, split

I can not write a regular expression allowing me to treat a string like:

```
xxx [[ob1:ch1|val1[[ob2:ch2|val2]]val1|val2[[ob3:ch3|val3|val3bis]]val2[[ob4:ch4]]val2]] xxx
```

My recursive tag is composed of : `[[object:field|value1|value2]]`

- 2 opening brackets
- one object name
- 2 points
- one field name
- an optional pipe and his value
- a second optional pipe and his value
- 2 closing brackets

In the example give abrove, I would like to get something like :

- [[ob1:ch1|val1[[ob2:ch2|val2]]val1|val2[[ob3:ch3|val3|val3bis]]val2[[ob4:ch4]]val2]]

  - ob1
  - ch1
  - val1[[ob2:ch2|val2]]val1
  - val2[[ob3:ch3|val3|val3bis]]val2[[ob4:ch4]]val2
- [[ob2:ch2|val2]]

  - ob2
  - ch2
  - val2
- [[ob3:ch3|val3|val3bis]]

  - ob3
  - ch3
  - val3
  - val3bis
- [[ob4:ch4]]

  - ob4
  - ch4

The following regexp can split each tag `(?=\[\[((?:[^\[\]]+|\[\[(?1)\]\])+)\]\])` but I can't analyse and split each pipe.

Comment: Regex is probably not the right tool for this job.

Comment: Wouldn't try this with RegEx, can't you use some other functions?

Comment: By repeating `valN`, do you mean a real duplicated string?

Comment: No, it can be any value